# Calibri font not loaded on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

On Chrome, the page https://diagonal.freelance-internet.com/ is displayed correctly with the Calibri font loaded by default

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: "Calibri";
   src: url("../fonts/Calibri.eot");
   src: url("../fonts/Calibri.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("../fonts/Calibri.otf") format("opentype"),
     url("../fonts/Calibri.ttf") format("truetype"),
     url("../fonts/Calibri.woff") format("woff"),
     url("../fonts/Calibri.woff2") format("woff2");
   font-weight: regular;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Oddly, in Firefox, it doesn't load and throws a 302 error code.

We can see it in the console, Network tab, and select "Fonts"

I tried replacing Calibri with another font, and on the other hand it is displayed fine on Firefox, as if there was only Calibri that FF refused to load!

An idea ??

Thanks :)

Comment: [error 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302). Also you have this error _downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Calibri" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:3) source: https://diagonal.freelance-internet.com/fonts/Calibri.woff_ for all your fonts even on Chrome

Comment: Thanks @Sfili_81, where can i see this message please ?

Comment: Ah damned you're right, i have an error on the foder name of my fonts... Thanks to you ;)

Comment: You can see this errors in your browser console